# PHP FastCGI Process Manager

Tags: php, fpm

Hi all programmers across the world! Can someone explain me detailed how the PHP FPM works in a HTTP request-response flow?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.  Best if you are specific about your question. Probably now the question is too broad to receive a good reply.

Comment: You should not use answer as comment space. Edit your original question.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you.
What I want to now is how the FPM works in a HTTP request-response flow. It can't be a complete detailed illustration, but something that I can have a better explanation of how the FPM works behind the scenes.